# Method Eat() receiving a string"food" and then compares it to "favFood"?

Tags: c#, string, comparison

EDIT: Resolved

I've recently started studying programming(c#) and currently working with inheritance and polymorphism.
I've done most of the coding already, but now im stuck.

This is the description I got, that I'm stuck on: The method Eat() receives a string(food) and compares it to the animals favourite food "favFood".

I've got a List for all the animals, including each ones favourite food, but I have no idea how to make a string(food) and compare it to the List. And where do I want the string?

(the code is waaay longer but I figured the rest dont matter rn. lemme know if I should post more of it.)
Thanks!

Edit: If the food is as that current animals "favFood" they eat it and, (hungry == false).
If its not "favFood" they dont eat it and (hungry == true)
I'm gonna post the rest of the code, as soon as I figure out how to post it in the correct format xd (im new here)

```
abstract class Animal
{
    protected int age { get; set; }
    protected string name { get; set; }
    protected string favFood { get; set; }
    protected string breed { get; set; }
    protected bool hungry { get; set; }
    public Animal(string name, int age, string favFood, string breed)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.favFood = favFood;
        this.breed = breed;

    }
    public virtual void Interact()  
    {
        
    }
    public virtual void HungryAnimal() 
    {

    }
    public virtual void Eat(string food)
    {
        // offer animal food from string, if "favFood" they eat and (hungry == false)
        // if not "favFood" HungryAnimal() (hungry == true)

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();    // Not sure this is correct
    }
}
class Petowner
{
    private int Age;
    private List<Animal> pets = new List<Animal>();
    public Petowner(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        pets.Add(new Cat(name:"Ellie", age: 3, favFood:"Fisk", breed:"Bondkatt"));
        pets.Add(new Cat(name:"Meelo", age:11, favFood:"Ost", breed:"Norsk skogskatt"));
        pets.Add(new Dog(name:"Sassa", age:6, favFood:"Korv", breed:"Husky"));
        pets.Add(new Puppy(name:"Majken", age:0, favFood:"Köttfärs", breed:"Pitbull"));
    }
    public void Feed()  // Sub-menu
    {
        int x = 0;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Vilket djur vill du mata?\n---------------------");
        PrintAnimals();
        try
        {
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Nu vart det fel, prova igen! (Välj med siffror)\n---------------------\nTryck på valfri tangent för att gå tillbaka...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
                pets[0].Eat();
                break;

            case 2:
                pets[1].Eat();                  
                break;
           
            case 3:
                pets[2].Eat();
                break;

            case 4:
                pets[3].Eat();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "The method Eat() receives a string(food) and compares it to the animals favourite food "favFood"."  Okay, you normally don't just compare things, you compare them and then do something based on the comparison.  What are you supposed to do with the comparison

Comment: What should happen if your pet gets its favourite food?

Comment: Just a hint: while I can imagine any `Animal` can `Eat` something and `Interact` with something, I have no clue what it should do when calling `HungryAnimal` on it

Comment: While I am suspecting that the excersize aims for teaching about string equality, "comparing" can mean many different things especially regarding strings. I guess we'll have to assume "check for (case insensitive) equality" is what the goal is?

Comment: Also this is too much code for Stack Overflow. Please reduce it to a [mre].

Comment: In C#, the `==` operator, when used on two strings can compare for equality. You could also use `string.Equals()`. More on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings

Comment: If you have solved this problem, please post the solution as an answer yourself and then mark it as accepted.